# Discrepancies in grabbing the z-index value on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody give me some insights why on chrome the grabbed value of the css zIndex element is "auto"? And it works fine on Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/K2WL4/4/

```
var tmp;
    var arr = [];

$('.note').each(function(){
        /* Finding the biggest z-index value of the notes */
        tmp = $(this).css('z-index');

         arr.push(tmp);
         zIndex = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
        alert(zIndex);
    })
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A known issue with Webkit browsers, detailed [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9667)

> I understand it being confusing that the computed z-index is auto when
>   you've specifically set one with .css, but RAMilewski makes a good
>   point that computed z-index will be different in different browsers.
>   We could lie (in a sense) and say that what was set is being applied
>   so that return values are consistent, or users can realize that the
>   z-index will not be applied without setting the other styles to make
>   z-index work. I'm closing wontfix as I suspect this will not be
>   something we will change, but if anyone disagrees, we can reopen in
>   the future.

Marked resolution is **Won't fix**. So don't expect this to go away anytime soon.

---

Jqueryu UI's [zIndex function](http://api.jqueryui.com/zIndex/) seems to have the same problem BTW: